# Div stays on div on mobile version

Tags: css

I'll show you my problem using screenshots. https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6PdH.png

This is a desktop version of footer. When I look on mobile version 5th column is on the 6th.

This is how it looks: http://responsivetest.net/#u=http://patwoj.hekko24.pl/wordpress|491|638|1 (bottom of page).

How do I change it to place a div below another div?

Comment: Increase the height of your 4th div :
col-lg-2 text-center

Comment: It is because you have applied inline height for every element

Comment: Please provide SO Snippet to receive any feedback.

Comment: if you apply inline height: it will apply for all the media queries. Best practice is to use different classes and assign height in particular Media queries.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to fix it without much modification in your code:

specify an id for the row

```
<!-- START: FOOTER -->
<div class="row" id="footer">
```

and add following code in your css file

```
@media screen and (max-width:1187px){
#footer .col-lg-1, #footer .col-lg-2, #footer .col-lg-2 div{height:auto !important;}
}
```

it will fix your issue.